# If a pull request is denied, do the commits still survive?

Tags: github, pull-request

If on gitHub, I do a pull request, and it's denied, and then I delete the fork that the commits where in, do the commits disappear, or will they still be in the pull request?

Comment: Did you delete your local repo copy?

Comment: @EduardoCobuci we'll stay yes (the question is if they can still be seen as part of the pull request)

Comment: If you had a forked repo and created a PR from it to the original repo, I'm pretty sure your code will be lost if you delete you fork.

Comment: Regarding the commits, yes the PR carries the commit history and has a source, your fork or branch. Can you tell exactly what happened?

Comment: @EduardoCobuci nothing. I am asking *if* I do that, what would happen. (Obviously, I want to know what would happen *before* I do it.)

Comment: Why don't you just try it with a scratch project?

Answer (score -1):

**Yes, the commit is lost** from github if you do a pull request that didn't get merged (so if it's closed or still open) and that you delete the fork.

However, the commit will of course survive locally unless you also delete your local repository.